# JavaScript three.js 3d engine: how to make object bigger by 20%?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I've got an object by:

```
planeWall=new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10,5,1,1), material);
```

Then I want to make it bigger, say, 20%
so I tried:

```
planeWall.geometry=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(12,6,1,1);
```

but failed,debugger says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'radius' of null
```

Is there anyone has some experience for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or similarly to Kuka's answer

```
planeWall.scale.multiplyScalar(1.2);
```

The idea is the transform properties(position,rotation,scale) are [Vector3](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-THREE.Vector3) instances so you can use the methods provided to easily transform your meshes.

Answer (score 2):

try `planeWall.scale.set(1.2,1.2,1.2);`